# Yii Header may not contain more than a single header

Tags: php, api, http, curl, yii

I have a problem when I am trying to POST data to third party API. I'm getting an error

```
yii\base\ErrorException: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in /www/wwwroot/xxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:382
```

As far as I know yii manages headers by itself and I added additional headers for auth purposes.
My additional headers:

```
protected function getHeaders($data = [])
    {
        ksort($data);
        reset($data);
        $ts = microtime().rand(0, 10000);

        return [
            'login: '.$this->login,
            'ts: '.$ts,
            'sig: '.md5($ts.$this->apiKey),
        ];
    }
```

Code works in pure php tests, but not inside yii app.

I already tried to log response and request headers, didn't find any duplicated headers.

Only something like this one:

```
'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

But I don't know if this counts for multiple headers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the API provider's side. My requests were not passing authentication, and I was getting back gibberish with incorrect headers.